# travis cannot parse my configuration file

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, travis-ci

I have a problem getting travis to run my tests. It stops during the parsing of my .travis.yml-file. 
You can have a look at the repository here: https://github.com/steve-korzinetzki/costcontrol

The content of the file is like the following:

```
language: php
php:
  - 5.5
  - hhvm

services: mysql

before_script:
  # installation
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --dev --prefer-source --no-interaction
  # database configuration
  - mysql -e 'create database cc_testing;'
  # startup server environment
  - php artisan migrate:install
  - php artisan migrate
  - php artisan migrate:install --env=”testing”
  - php artisan serve
  - sleep 5

script:
  - phpunit
  - vendor/bin/behat
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: An error occured while trying to parse your .travis.yml file.

Please make sure that the file is valid YAML.

http://lint.travis-ci.org can check your .travis.yml.

The error was "'reader' unacceptable character '' (0x80) special characters are not allowed

in "'reader'", position 373 at line 0 column 0".
```

I think there is an error in the charset of the file. But I don't get it. One fun fact: travis validation page says the file is fine (see http://lint.travis-ci.org/steve-korzinetzki/costcontrol).

Did anyone have similar problems? Does anyone know the solution? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this script run. Error was not in first line. It was the wrong " later on

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong kind of hyphen in mine which was impossible to see, again the linter said the yaml was valid but the build would not run.

To track down the rogue character, treat the .yml as a single line and count in the number of characters given by *in "'reader'", position XXX*